# How to retain info when clicking a link to another page

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic4

I am making an app with Ionic 4 that displays vouchers (images) fetched from a database. I want each image that's displayed to be a link to a separate details page that shows more info for that specific voucher. However, I am having trouble finding a way to retain the selected voucher's info so the details page knows which voucher to display. I know I can store data locally with IonicStorage, but I don't know how to get the current voucher's data into the typescript side so that it can be set. The only way I know how to do this is with ngModel, but that only works for forms/input.

HTML:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let voucher of vouchers" >
  <ion-label> 
    <a routerLink="/details" routerDirection="forward (click)="openDetails()"><img src='http://example.com/imgs/vouchers/{{voucher.photo}}'></a>

  </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

TS:

```
public voucherName:string;
.
.
.
openDetails()
{
  console.log(this.voucherName);
  this.storage.set('name', this.voucherName);
}
```

I want {{voucher.photo}} or {{voucher.name}} (the name property of the current voucher data) to be stored into the TS variable 'voucherName' so that it can be locally stored and therefore used to display the voucher's info in the details page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass voucher as parameter of openDetails as

HTML

```
(click)="openDetails(voucher)"
```

In ts code

```
openDetails(voucher)
{
  console.log(voucher.voucherName + '-' + voucher.photo);
  this.storage.set('name', voucher.voucherName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store it in local storage at all, that's not really Angular way of doing things.

Instead, you should use routing with parameters:

```
{
  path: "details/:name/",
  component: DetailsComponent
},
```

And send the name/id over router:

```
[routerLink]="['/details', voucher.name]"
```

Then subscribe to router in the details component:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)

this.route.params.subscribe(params =>
  console.log(params.name); // Name of your clicked voucher
);
```